# Solve a matrix equation in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, debugging

I want to solve this in MATLAB

F *Y + Y *F'= - G' *G

I wrote this code:

```
Y= solve(F2 *Y + Y *F2'== - G1' *G1  ,Y);
```

But I get this Error!

```
 Undefined function or variable 'Y'.
```

Can you tell me **how to declare the matrix Variable  Y** ??

Comment: How are you defining your other variables? There's no such thing as a "matrix variable." Assuming `Y` is symbolic, it can either be declared as a scalar as a fixed size matrix using `Y = sym('Y',[3,3])`. I recommend reading the documentation on [Matlab's symbolic math](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/).

Comment: Y is the unknown variable here..everything else are given

Comment: Take some time and go back to all of your previous questions and mark the most helpful answer that solves your problem as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/335102) by clicking **`✔`**, on the left side of the answer, to turn them green so that the community may know that your problem is solved. You can also [upvote if you have 15 reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/335102) if you like by clicking on **`△`**, on the left side of the answers

Answer (score 2):

use syms if variable Y is not known

for example:

```
 syms y
 solve(2*y-4==0)
```

---

```
 ans= 2
```

to specify the matrix eq you should define the size of y:

```
 y=sym('y',[2,1]);
 A=[1 0;0 1];
 c=[1;2];
 z=[0;0];
 B=solve(A*y-c==z);
```

B is a structure which stores value of y1 and y2

```
 B.y1
 ans= 
      1
```